# Manipulating with bit representation of int

Tags: java, int, short

I have some `int` and `short` like this:

```
int a = //...
short b = //..
```

What is the fastest way to craft `int c` with the following bit representation:

- 2nd and 3rd most significant bytes of `a` consists of bytes representation of `b`.
- The rest of the bytes of `a` are left unchanged.

Maybe bitwise `OR` will help here but still dont see how.

For example:

```
a = 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101
b =          11111111 11111111
```

Then we have

```
c = 01010101 11111111 11111111 01010101
```

Comment: Could you give an example input and output? Maybe together with a bit representation to see the math you wish to implement.

Comment: @Zabuza Added some example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove what used to be in those bytes, then put in `b`:

```
c = (a & 0xFF0000FF) | ((b << 8) & 0x00FFFF00);
```

The extra `&` after the shift is to counteract the sign-extension, which would otherwise overwrite the top byte with 1's whenever `b` is negative.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit why yoy shifter b 8 bits left?

Comment: @St.Antario in order to align it with the middle two bytes, you can see in your own diagram that `b` is moved 8 bits to the left too.

Comment: Ah, I see. It means it is cast to int and then shifted by 8 bits. Thank you.